# 3:1 matching with MatchIt in R. The number of matched control is not equal to 3 times the number of cases

Tags: r, matching

Hello I'm using the `MatchIt` package in R

I have a total of unmatched 116 treated cases and 462 unmatcehd non-treated case

with the command

```
mod_match_logit = matchit(f.build("treatement_yes_or_no", covariates), 
method = "nearest", distance = "logit", data = df, caliper = 0.05, ratio = 3)
```

I get then a result of 91 matched treated cases with 248 matched non treated cases. What I don't understand is that, with a 3:1 matching, I should have 91*3 = 273 matched non treated cases (and not 248). Per default is the command `replace` set to `F` in `MatchIt`, so it doesn't explain the difference for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the data I am only guessing but it is most likely due to your caliper setting.

MatchIt defines the caliper as "the number of standard deviations of the distance measure within which to draw control units (default = 0, no caliper matching)"(p.26)

Therefore my guess is you have some units in the treatment group with high propensity scores that cannot be matched to those in the untreated group (at least within 0.05 standard deviations as you specified). The reason why you are not getting 273 subjects in your matched data set is because of the caliper = 0.05 setting in your MatchIt call. Some of the treated subjects with higher propensity scores that are still getting matched to at least one untreated are unable to get matched to a second or third because they are beyond the 0.05 caliper specification.
Maybe increasing the caliper would retain more treated subjects but I would not go any higher than 0.25 based on best practices documented in the literature.

Depending on your research design you could consider using other matching methods. For example you could use distances other than euclidean such as mahalanobis which is an option in MatchIt.  Alternatively, you could also use either optimal full matching or optimal pair matching from the 'optmatch' library though you can also call those through the MatchIt function. There are many other approaches but these are easily accessible from the MatchIt library. The literature does suggest trying a few different methods and then checking for balance as long as you do not "cherry-pick" the one that gives you the largest effect. In other words select your matched set based on covariate balance and not on the outcome variable in your study. There is definitely a bit of an art to propensity score matching but is why I think it so interesting!

Comment: Thank you ver much for your answer @JasonJohnson. As you talked a bout literature, what is an accepted threshold to judge the quality of the matching as sufficient: <0.25 mean standardised difference or <0.25 standardised difference for each single variable or <0.1 mean standardised difference or <0.1 standardised difference for each single variable?

Comment: Yes to assess balance you would want each of the matching variables to below the threshold and the lower the better of course.  The literature suggests all matching variables should have standardized mean differences below 0.05. However, if you have any variables after matching with standardized mean differences above 0.05 but less than 0.25 then you would want to control for those variables in your final outcome analysis. If any variables are above 0.25 then you should consider a different matching strategy so that the treated and untreated groups are comparable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you again @JasonJohnson. I upvoted your answer. Could you provide a link for the references talking about which threshold should be used for standardized mean difference?

Comment: Stuart (2010) -https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2943670/ is a great summary article (refers to MatchIt as well as other R packages) and for the 0.25 threshold she references Rubin (2001) - https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1020363010465

Comment: Also one other issue with regards to balance is what standard deviation to use for standardized mean differences. The default of MatchIt is to use the one for treatment group but in the Rosenbaum (2010) book Design of Observational Studies, he makes a good case to use a pooled one where equal weight is given to the treatment group and control group (see page 187-188). I use this one and have created my own functions for it. Though it is still a work in progress here are my propensity score matching R functions: https://github.com/jasonrpro/Propensity-Score-Matching-in-R

Comment: The functions are basically wrappers for existing functions of R packages but help me organize the steps and allow more flexibility. The README explains the parameters. If interested feel free to check them out and since I just started uploading to Github feel free to leave feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answers @JasonJohnson. That really helped a lot. However the answer to the original question is stil not 100% crystal clear to me (and that's why I'm not accepting the answer with the green arrow yet). But again thank you very much for your time and references

Comment: Sorry! Well the reason why you are not getting 273 subjects in your matched data set is because of the caliper=0.05 setting in your MatchIt call. Some of the treated subjects with higher propensity scores that are still getting matched to at least one untreated are unable to get matched to a second or third because they are beyond the 0.05 caliper specification.

Comment: Thanks you a lot @JasonJohnson. It might have been only a rephrasing of already given statement in your answer but your last statement is the one which  helped the most answer the question (und actually confirmed what I got in the meantime from another source). Therefore I edited your answer by adding your comment. Please edit it further if you want, just leave the part with your last comment. Once you will have reviewed, I'll be glad to accept it as the best answer. Thank you again for your patience

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have reviewed and you can accept that as the answer.  If you have any other questions feel free to message me either here or on Github. Best of luck!